# Output PERL to a .txt file and to screen

Tags: perl, text

Here's what I have.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$numbertotal = 0;
$filecount = 0;

open my $thisfile, '<', "files.txt" or die $!;

while (<$thisfile>) {
    ($thisdate, $thistime, $thisampm, $thissize, $thisname) = split;

    $numbertotal += $thissize;
    $filecount += 1;
    printf "%10d     %-25.25s\n", $thissize, $thisname;
}

$averagefilesize = $numbertotal / $filecount;

print "Total files:  ",$filecount,"      Average file size:  ",$averagefilesize," bytes\n";
```

I would like to take the 2 different print lines and send them to another file that will be created by the code.  I know that it will use the '<' operation but I'm having an issue figuring it out.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to print to STDOUT and to a file? I'm not sure I follow the question. Have you looked into TEE?

Comment: Yes. I would like to print to screen and to the file.  To screen just to see what I'm doing without having to open the other file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write to a file, you open it with `'>'`:

```
open my $thisfile, '<', "files.txt" or die $!;
open my $thatfile, '>', 'output.txt' or die $!;

while (<$thisfile>) {
    ($thisdate, $thistime, $thisampm, $thissize, $thisname) = split;

    $numbertotal += $thissize;
    $filecount += 1;
    printf $thatfile "%10d     %-25.25s\n", $thissize, $thisname;
}
close $thatfile;
close $thisfile;
```

Comment: The addition of the other file at the beginning is what I was forgetting.  I added that 'open' statement and added two print lines to my code and it is working like I wanted it to.     Thanks for the help and speed.